# how to store/replace local variable in debugger lldb in Xcode

Tags: swift, xcode, lldb

I am new to Xcode and came by pycharm. In pycharm, I am able to use watcher to execute the statement and store as local variable in debugger mode. How could I do that same thing from Xcode debugger lldb?
for example

```swift
let a = 5
letba = 5
let aPlusb = Self.addFunc(a, b)
```

after place debugger on line 3. how can i call Self.addFunc() and store into some variable `xy`

I have tried expression or e under `lldb` and then `po xy` but it does not work with error

```
error: expression failed to parse:
error: <EXPR>:8:1: error: cannot find 'xy' in scope
`xy`
```

Comment: How are you encountering LLDB? Do you mean the REPL?

Comment: `lldb` not REPL

Comment: Yes, but how did you get to lldb? You opened the Terminal and what?

Comment: IIUC, `xy` is not a variable that already exists in your program, but rather a variable you are trying to create in the debugger so that you can store some value in it and then recall the value later on in your debug session.  Is that right?

Comment: And from context, I'm guessing you are debugging a swift program.  The reference to pycharm is just to say "I can do X debugging in pycharm, can I do X debugging in swift".  Is that right?

Comment: @JimIngham exactly for both point how can I do that?

Comment: @matt from xcode debugger window. I can access lldb

Comment: So you are debugging something? What are you debugging? Is it a Swift project? What kind of project? How did you come fall into the debugger? At a breakpoint? There is no such thing in Swift as `Self.func()` so what did you really say?

Comment: I have one project that implement with other modal as class. And yes  I place breakpoint to debugger the inheritance function

Answer (score 0):

You're right that the expression parser is the command you want to use to create scratch variables that can record values in lldb.  There are two ways to do this.

First of all, when you evaluate any expression using lldb's expression parser, lldb creates a "result variable" which stores the result of the expression:

```
(lldb) expr myVar
(Int) $R0 = 10
```

This can be used in future expressions, e.g.:

```
(lldb) expr print($R0)
10
```

The other way you can do this is to take advantage of the lldb convention that an identifier in an lldb expression which begins with a `$` is treated as an lldb "persistent declaration", and can be used in future expressions.  Except for a very few exceptions like this, lldb parses expressions exactly as they would be in source code compiled in the context of the current frame.  So you just use the same syntax you would use to define the identifier in swift, so:

```
(lldb) expr var $myVar = 10
(lldb) expr print($myVar)
10
```

BTW, I'm not being abstruse using "identifier" instead of "variable" above. The same convention holds for other instances of identifiers, e.g. for type and function definitions as well.